# Ember-cli-notifications not showing icons

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i'm trying to use the [Ember-cli-notifications](https://github.com/Blooie/ember-cli-notifications) in my new app, but the icon is not working at all.

Following the documentation, i need put this i n my configuration file:

```
  'ember-cli-notifications': {
    icons: 'bootstrap'
  }
```

And i already did.. but still, nothing happens and no error shows in my console or terminal.

Somethings this add-ons have poor documentation.. so, anyone who understand embers better them i do.. could answer me if i'm missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: you do have bootstrap in your app, right?

Comment: Nop, i'm not using anything like that.. i just installed the app, as the documentation say @AcidBurn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for the notifications addon are clear:

> Alternatively, you can use Glyphicons that are packaged with Bootstrap. Glyphicons are **not** added to your application via this addon.

So you'll have to add bootstrap and import the glyphicons into your project.

You can run `$ bower install bootstrap` (or do a custom build with just the icons at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

And then in your ember-cli-build.js file, import the icons:

```
// /ember-cli-build.js
app.import('vendor/bootstrap_custom/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff', { destDir: 'fonts' });
app.import('vendor/bootstrap_custom/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2', { destDir: 'fonts' });
app.import('vendor/bootstrap_custom/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf', { destDir: 'fonts' });
```

Make sure you replace "vendor/bootstrap_custom/" with whatever path you saved the fonts at.